# Connect Power Automate to outlook OWA

Tags: outlook, power-automate, outlook-web-app

The company I work for use a custom OWA address, https://owa.domain.com. They also block access to the standard https://outlook.live.com/owa/ address through zscaler.

Is there a way to get Power Automate to connect to the custom OWA domain link the company uses?

Thanks.

I tried changing the connection in Power Automate but there was no option to use OWA as a connector.

Comment: Which connector are you using?

Comment: I've tried both Outlook V2 and Outlook V3 versions for the when an email is received connector.

Answer (score 0):

Since OWA is part of Microsoft Exchange server, think this might come in handy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/exchange

> The Exchange Server actions enable you to connect to an Exchange server and manage your correspondence.

Otherwise, good ol' SMTP might do the trick: https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/nl-nl/connectors/details/shared_smtp/smtp/. Connect this in PowerAutomate using the following steps:

1. Go to PowerAutomate
2. Go to connections (adapt URL so it ends on /connections)
3. Make new (up left)
4. Search for (up right) "SMTP"
5. Fill in your OWA details

Little word of caution: with MFA you might need to use apppasswords to get authenticated, which is not a security best practice but hey it just might work. Apppasswords at the time of writing to be created @ https://mysignins.microsoft.com/security-info > "add sign-in method" > app password.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35783952)

Comment: @KeyboardCat thanks for helping the newbie out. How are these edits?

Comment: Looks good to me! Thanks for adding the details.